# HTTP POST constrain by payload datatype?

Tags: http, xampp, webserver, esp32

I am using esp32 with IDF framework. My task is to upload data to a server from esp32. I made a dummy server using XAMP in laptop where data from esp32 is being uploaded. Basically, I read characters from a file in esp32 and use HTTP post to send data to XAMP server where I create a file in append mode.

I noticed that when I send characters, the upload speed I get is 460KB/sec, on the other hand when I send raw binary data, the upload speed is 262 KB/sec. I don't understand why because the amount of payload in each POST is 4KB in both case.

I thought HTTP is data agnostic, it shouldn't matter what data I upload to the server. The speed should be same in both the case.

Edit 1:
I read the content of a file from USB flash drive and post it via HTTP post.

```
static void file_operations(void) {
    static FILE *file;
    static size_t read_bytes;
    static const char *directory = "/usb/esp";
    static const char *file_path = "/usb/esp/book.bin";

    file = fopen(file_path, "rb");

    while (1) {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        read_bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer) - 2, file);
        buffer[8191] = '\0';
        if (read_bytes <= 0) {
            break;  // End of file reached
        } else {
            err = post_rest_function();
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

static esp_err_t post_rest_function(void) {
    static char *post_data = buffer;
        esp_http_client_set_post_field(client, post_data, strlen(post_data)));
        esp_err_t err = esp_http_client_perform(client);
        return err;
}
```

config_post is defined in main:

```
esp_http_client_config_t config_post = {
    .url = "http://192.168.10.21/uploads/upload_file.php",
    .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
    .cert_pem = NULL,
    .keep_alive_enable = 1,
};

client = esp_http_client_init(&config_post);
```

If I use filepath with a file which has characters (file1.txt), the speed is twice the file which has binary raw data (file2.bin).

Edit 2: I did further testing and analyze the packets through Wireshark. I noticed that payload in the TCP segment has reduced to 167 bytes automatically from 1440 bytes.

Comment: Share your code. We have no idea what you’re actually doing without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry! I have cleaned and uploaded the code. Please check it.

Comment: found the issue: strlen(post_data)